# q key not recognized

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have an ASUS ROG G752-VSK gaming laptop that I recently installed Ubuntu on.
During the installation, keyboard did not work so I had to plug an external USB keyboard to finish the installation.

After booting up, I noticed that the keyboard started working again however this time the functionality keys and backlighting was not working, also the q key stopped working completely.

Considering it a kernel issue, I went ahead and manually updated to the latest Linux kernel. This fixed the backlighting and function keys, however the q key remains non-functional.

I've done a few different troubleshooting attempts, and tried out basically a ton of different suggestions:

1. Important to note, the keypress is not being detected.

I tried out xev,scancodes, etc, updated the system, upgraded all apps and other different ways, installed some old packages for reconfiguring the keyboard, changed the keyboard locale multiple times, went in the dkpg keyboard utilities. Changed system settings, even messed with ACPI parameter and GRUB settings. Nothing I ever did indicated any response from key.

This is not a hardware issue, this key has been working yesterday on W10.

Anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @K7AAY I did not install Ubuntu alongside WIndows. Main and only OS is Ubuntu now.

Comment: _Nebojša Jotanović_ I would suggest redownloading it then verifying the download by checksum https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and trying the newly downloaded ISO on a LiveUSB https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0 or https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0